# How to dispose Gluon PopupView?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have a ChoiceFieldComponent which shows a `PopupView` when it is clicked on. The content of the `PopupView` is a custom ChoiceMenu showing a list of cocktail ingredients. As the number of ingredients for a recipe varies, it is possible to add / remove a ChoiceField.

When a ChoiceField is removed from its parent `View`, there seems to remain a strong reference, which prevents the ChoiceField and the ChoiceMenu from getting garbage collected.

I think this is happening because `PopupView` holds a reference to both nodes:

```
popup = new PopupView(getSkinnable(), choiceMenu);
```

I have tried to remove the reference to `choiceMenu` by:

```
BorderPane container = (BorderPane) popup.lookup(".container");
container.setCenter(null);
```

But there is still the reference to `PopupView.ownerNode` (ChoiceField), which I can not clear. 
Because the number of `PopupViews` is increasing with every ChoiceField added, I wonder if there is a way to remove a `PopupView`.

Comment: The PopupView is removed from the scene graph by the glassPane after it is hidden. You can check `MobileApplication.getInstance().getGlassPane().getLayers()`, and see that the PopupView is not there. But this doesn't mean that the PopupView reference is released. Can't you remove that instance (instead of the owner node), and create the PopupView when required?

Comment: Thanks José. I haven't noticed in ScenicView when a PopupView was removed, because it was so many of them. I followed your advice and created the `PopupView` on demand, which revealed that the strong reference is coming from a `ListProperty` which I used to store the ingredients list

Comment: The parent view is initialized much faster now, nice! I just would like to get rid of this fade in effect when the `PopupView`  shows. Setting a `NoTransition" to the popup didn't work.